# when click outside dropdown menu default value should appear

Tags: jquery

**This is my html select:**

```
<select name='gender' class="defaultvalue" style="width: 100%;">
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
  <option>Male</option>   
  <option>Female</option>                                                                    
</select>
```

**This is my jquery function:**

```
// Hide default value.
$(".defaultvalue").focus(function()
{
    var first = $(this).find("option").eq(0);
    if(first.val() === "")
    {
        first.remove();
    }
});

$(document).on("click", function() 
{
      // Code here.
});
```

I am trying that when i click outside the dropwdown without selecting any value it should display again the defualt select option (Select Option) which i am hiding it when i click on the dropdwn button. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try this. http://jsfiddle.net/Y5MRz/. It's default behavior of dropdown.

Comment: but i donot want to show the "Select Option" in the list thts why i am hiding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
$(".defaultvalue").append("<option value='' selected='1'>Select Option</option>");
```

This will add the above Select option to dropdown and it will select it too. You also need to check whether above option already exist in select before appending it.

Comment: yes it is working. it has one problem though. When i click on any option it select the "Select Option" always.

Comment: Did you figured it out??

Comment: use:`$(document).click(function(evt){

       if(evt.target.class== "defaultvalue")
          return;

      //Do processing of click event here for every element except with classs defaultvalue

});`